# How to add headers to Common Data Service data store in Microsoft Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, powerapps, common-data-service

I am new to Azure Data Factory and have a requirement to pull data from Common Data Service (PowerApps) application to Azure SQL Database.
I can pull data directly from the entities using a linked service. The problem arises when I want to include headers such as

```
OData-MaxVersion:4.0
OData-Version:4.0
Prefer:odata.include-annotations=*
```

into my pipeline. The reason for adding these headers is that my entity uses values from different option sets and when I use the above headers in my web api calls, I get the response with formatted values as well.
Please advise how can I get around this problem using Common Data Service connectors available in Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those headers will expand the attributes like Picklist (optionset) for the formatted values in CRM web api. Are you getting the picklist integer column values in query results?

Because there seems to be couple of issues [opened in github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/28027)  stating the results are missing. You should try schema/mapping to bring those attributes. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/ajitpatra365crm/posts/azure-copy-data-from-d365-ce-to-azure-sql-database-using-azure-data-factory) .

Or use the OData connector instead of Dynamics/CDS connectors.

Comment: I used a rest api connector as it provides out of box functionality for adding headers. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @sameet90 glad to hear. not sure why your comment was posted twice :)